# full screen and rotate to landscape virtual keyboard

Tags: android

Hi I am now developing a chat application and I am using a floating window for my chat

[image]
[image]

when focus that edit text and keyboard should like this but my activity orientation is portrait not landscape

[image]

So as we know that floating window is separated from activity. This floating window can also rotate without changing the orientation of my current activity and I achieve that, however I have edit text and when a focus on it,  it shows portrait keyboard and I already know that's what will happen

So my goal is to full screen my soft keyboard and change it's orientation to landscape without changing the orientation of my current activity?

Is there a way to do this? 
Please guide me.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your question. Please, try to reformulate it. A screen recording of your app might be of great value here.

Comment: @webo80 wait sir I'll create a presentation

Comment: @webo80 done sir.

Comment: @webo80 Thanks. So your problem is the portrait full-screen keyboard is hiding your activity / floating view?

Comment: no sir. I just want the keyboard to be same orientation as my floating window which is landscape and to be fullscreen

what I shown in pic #3 is what I wanted. sorry if it's not clear

but my activity orientation is portrait

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to control the rotation of the software keyboard. It's linked to the screen orientation of your activity.

However, you can control your activity orientation.

Comment: I see. but that's what's my problem is sir
I wanted to change my keyboard orientation without affecting activity or depending to activity :(

Comment: @Beginner then, I affirm my response. There is no way to control the rotation of the software keyboard independiently from your app